# 連想配列に対して、lengthも減る削除がしたいです

Tags: javascript, html

現在下記のソースのようにspliceを用いた実装をしたのですが、

```js
filtered_files.splice('key', 1);
```

目的の要素が削除されません。

lengthも減る要素の削除方法があれば、ご教授をお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascriptの連想配列は[`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)ではなくて、[`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)ですから、`length`とのプロパティがありません。要素数を取得するには下記のように[`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)を用いると一番便利だと思います。

```
var hash = { key1: "value 1", key2: "value 2"};
var hash = Object.keys(hash).length;
```

要素の削除には、[delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)演算子が使用できます：

```
delete hash.key1;
```

または

```
delete hash['key1'];
```

Answer (score 0):

・まず連想配列にはLengthの概念はないので、

```js
var hogeArr = { hoge1 : "h" , hoge2 : "o" , hoge3 : "g" , hoge4 : "e" };

var count = 0;
for(var j in hogeArr){
    count++;
}
alert(count);
```

でLengthを数えるみたいですね。

・lengthの減る削除方法はないので、

```js
// 連想配列を生成する
var myObj = { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2', key3: 'value3' };

// 連想配列のキー(key2)を削除する
delete myObj['key2'];
```

で削除します